# Adding a dynamic binding between the menu bar and the calendar's month

Tags: angularjs

The code for my nav bar is:

```
<nav class="{{active}}" ng-model="active">
<h2> &nbsp &nbsp  Months </h2> 
<a href="#" class="jan" ng-click="active='jan'">January</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="feb" ng-click="active='feb'">February</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="mar" ng-click="active='mar'">March</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="apr" ng-click="active='apr'">April</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="may" ng-click="active='may'">May</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="jun" ng-click="active='jun'">June</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="jul" ng-click="active='jul'">July</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="aug" ng-click="active='aug'">August</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="sep" ng-click="active='sep'">September</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="oct" ng-click="active='oct'">October</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="nov" ng-click="active='nov'">November</a> <br>
<a href="#" class="dec" ng-click="active='dec'">December</a> <br>

</nav>
```

How do i make the binding between the selected month on the nav bar and the month shown in the calendar? I am using the Angular UI calendar directive for adding custom evens. Here is the Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/fED6FBPVdlSMOkTvnyZj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you can go through the  [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) you can find an API to do so. The API is

```
.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date )
```

On click of any month from navigation bar you can do something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="jan" ng-click="changeMonth('jan')">January</a> <br>
```

Inside the controller, create that method :

```
$scope.changeMonth(monthName){
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("calender");
  ele = angular.element(ele); // just check if u need this step or not
  var date - new Date();

  switch(monthName){
    case 'jan' :
      date.setMonth(1);
      break;
    case 'feb' :
      date.setMonth(2);
      break;
   // other months...
  }

  ele.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date );
}
```

Comment: I tried using gotoDate: 
$scope.JanClick = function () {
      $scope.calendar.fullCalendar('gotoDate', 2016, 1);
  }

And tried calling this function on ng-click. It still doesn't work.

Comment: date is a javascript/moment object in the API Doc. Please read the doc carefully. stackoverflow is meant for directing one in right direction, not a place where you can copy and paste so that things will start working.

Comment: i used the following function in my controller: $scope.JanClick = function () {
 uiCalendarConfig.calendars['myCalendar1'].fullCalendar('gotoDate', 2016, 0);
  }  It changes the calendar month on clicking january to January 1970. what is the problem ?

Comment: Its difficult to understand what is wrong here, I dont know how could I help you.